# Regular expression for multiple words with * and space

Tags: java, regex

My regular expression is of format "Exit* Order*". When i use in java its not working as expected.

```
String pattern = "Exit* Order*";
String ipLine = "Exiting orders";
```

Match: NO

```
String pattern = "Exit Order";
String ipLine = "Exit order";
```

Match: Yes.

Java Code:
        Pattern patrn = Pattern.compile(pattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher match = patrn.matcher(ipLine);

Can any one let me know what should be the pattern in such cases.

Comment: Please add more relevant code. Note that if you really use a regex, you need to use `.*` match 0 or more characters other than newline or `\S*` to match 0 or more non-whitespace characters.

Comment: Thanks!! I am using java regular expression classes.

Comment: Take a look in some basic regexp tutorial.  You simply use it wrong.  `*` does not mean any number of any character.  It means any occurrence of preceding character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like:

```
"Exit.* Order.*"
```

or maybe something instead of `.*`, e.g. `\S*`, `\w*`, `[A-Za-z]*`.

Your current regular expression is looking for zero or more `t` and `r` on the ends of the words, e.g. it would match

```
Exi Orde
Exit Orde
Exitt Orde
Exi Order
Exi Orderr
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Exit\\w* Order\\w*
```

You should use this.`.*` can match much more than intended.use `i` or `ignorecase` flag

Comment: `\\w` would be better, so you don't match `Exit^&%#$&^% Order)&^%&`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just want to match "Exit Order" case-insensitively:

Try this:

```
if (str.matches("(?i)exit order"))
```

Or to restrict the match to just your examples, where the "O" of "Order may be "o", use:

```
if (str.matches("Exit [Oo]rder"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Java does not use Linux regexp expression:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Use this:

```
String pattern = "Exit.* Order.*";
```

Comment: Both "Linux" regexp and Java regexp use `.*` to denote "any number occurrence of any character".  The difference does not comes from your so-called "Linux regexp"